# Error being thrown when load a map from a KML

Tags: java, android, google-maps, inputstream, kml

I am loading a map in my app from kml files (with a different kml file on each day of the week being loaded). It was working until just recently and I'm really confused as to why I am getting this error as I haven't touched this part of my code since I got it working basically and now I am getting a XmlPullParserException: expected: /META read: HEAD (position:END_TAG @1:355 in java.io.InputStreamReader@426ba9d0)

Here is my code:

```
// set kml layers
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int value = preferences.getInt("DateStarted", 1);

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(value));
    System.out.println("In Maps start day is " + String.valueOf(value));
    try {
        // get different maps on different days of the week
        switch(value) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/monday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/tuesday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
               inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/wednesday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/thursday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/thursday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/saturday.kml").openStream();
            break;
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/sunday.kml").openStream();
            break;
         }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the full error message that I'm getting is :

```js
> W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: /META read: HEAD (position:END_TAG </HEAD>@1:355 in java.io.InputStreamReader@426ba9d0) 
W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEndTag(KXmlParser.java:970)
W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:372)
W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlParser.parseKml(KmlParser.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlLayer.<init>(KmlLayer.java:49)
W/System.err:     at com.example.veronika.grabble.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
W/System.err:     at aai.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
W/System.err:     at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420218b0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.veronika.grabble.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:176)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
                      at aai.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                      at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I should go about fixing this? Because I don't understand where does the null pointer exception comes from...
PS: the log.d shows that value has a value in one of the cases, and so that should put a different inputStream than null ....

Comment: obviously you are not getting xml but html fx http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/404.kml

Comment: sorry, it wasn't an error in coding, i had forgotten to turn on the wifi after restarting my phone. PS: the links are to kml files, they work fine now